# Get Latitude-Longitude Value from Distance value from Drawing Route in Android

Tags: android

I have two Geopoints

```
GeoPoint gp1; 
GeoPoint gp2;
```

I also have distance between these two geopoints. As of now it is 174 km. I need accurate middle geopoint between this two geopoint's so how can I get Middle GeoPoint.

Above two GeoPoint is Part of Route Draw which is not straight so i need Middle Point of Drawing route not straight line

my code:

```
List<GeoPoint> _geopoints = decodePoly(_path);
GeoPoint gp1; 
GeoPoint gp2; 
gp2 = _geopoints.get(0);
System.out.println("gp2 "+gp2);                                           
System.out.println("_geopoints"+_geopoints.size());
System.out.println("_midgeopoint"+_geopoints.size()/2);       
mGeoPointMiddleOne=_geopoints.get(_geopoints.size()/2);


private List<GeoPoint> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<GeoPoint> poly = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (((double) lat / 1E5) * 1E6),
                    (int) (((double) lng / 1E5) * 1E6));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
```

above function decoePoly(path) is responsible for drawing route between two geopoints so i get route between two points.

and i also get distance between these two geopoints from calling Google map api for drawing route which is below

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?  origin=52.31,16.71&destination=51.27,6.75&sensor=false
```

so i get distance between two points from  tag in web services

so my requirment is how can i get latitude-longitude at middle distance value from this route?

Comment: I added a link to my answer. Please see it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is "Co-ordinate Geometry" and you are looking for "equation of a straight line".

Here goes, a interesting [link](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/study_guide/Equations-of-Lines.topicArticleId-18851,articleId-18845.html) on the internet.

Comment: my requirement is find middle point of route which is zigzag manner not in straight line.

Comment: You mean, mid point along the path of the route ? In that case, edit your question, its misleading and a waste of people's time.

Answer (score 0):

I think distance value is not necessary if you have two GeoPoints. Analytical geometry says that if you know coordinates of two points you can calculate middle point simply.

If you have specific route which is not straight line.

**See this page: [GO](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26726/get-the-latlon-of-middle-points-of-a-road-segment)**

[image]

Comment: The great-circle or orthodromic distance is the shortest distance between any two points on the surface of a sphere.  What you show is an approximation that will work for short distances.  The OP needs to be aware of that.

Comment: @jimmcnamara: my requirement is find middle point of route which is zigzag manner not in straight line